# How to replace underscore with string?

Tags: java

How to replace underscore with string in java? I tried to use replace method but it didn't work

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String value = "Once upon a time there _________  man called Damocles";
        String result = value.replace('_', 'michief');
        System.out.println(result);
     }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing the single quotes with double quotes.

Comment: (deleted my comment because answers already cover it and because I made a silly mistake with my regex and it was too late to edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `Strings` in Java need to be in double-quotes. So you need to use `"_"` and `"mischief"` instead of `'_'` and `'mischief'`.

Secondly, `replace("_", "mischief")` will replace all the occurrences of the underscore with the word "mischief". Since your input string has more than one underscore, you'll get something like "mischiefmischiefmischief".

To fix this, use `replaceFirst` to only replace the first underscore, and then use `replace` to remove all the other underscores:

```java
public static void main(String []args){
    String value = "Once upon a time there _________ man called Damocles";
    String result = value.replaceFirst("_", "michief");  // replace the first underscore with "mischief"
    result = result.replace("_", "");  // remove the other underscores by replacing them with the empty string
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: That’s double the work. `replaceFirst` works with regular expressions.

Comment: Yes, but I'm going for a simpler explanation that OP will understand rather than efficiency here. Clearly since OP is using single quotes for strings they are a beginner

Comment: Also `result = result.replace("_", "")` would remove all `_` regardless of their placement, which may not be what OP wants. For instance in case of `Foo ___ bar ___ baz` OP may want to put word only in first `__` *without removing second*. For that `replaceFirst("_+", "michief")` may be safer choice.

Answer (score 2):

[`replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) can replace [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) patterns:

```java
String result = value.replaceFirst("_+", "michief");
```

The regular expression `_+` matches one or more consecutive underscores.

(As already noted by others, you also need to use `"…"` instead of `'…'` for strings in Java.)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String[] args){
        String text = "There are lot of text ____  and underscore in this string";
        // this line replace first parameter text with second parameter 
        String newText = text.replace("_", "expected text for each underscore");
        System.out.println(newText);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a behind-the-scenes approach to understand what's going on without using regex (although not the best solution), take a look at this:

```
String originalText = "Once upon a time there _________  man called Damocles";
String wordToReplace = "mischief";

// get the first and last index of the underscore substring sequence
// assuming that there are no other characters in between underscores
int firstIndexOfUnderscore = originalText.indexOf("_");
int lastIndexOfUnderscore = originalText.lastIndexOf("_", firstIndexOfUnderscore);

// get the full underscore substring
String underscoreSubstring = originalText.substring(firstIndexOfUnderscore, lastIndexOfUnderscore + 1);

// replace the full underescore substring with the word to replace
originalText.replace(underscoreSubstring, wordToReplace)
```